# How to involve a Collection on a spring transaction?

Tags: spring, transactions

I currently have a spring application with hibernate and a PlataformTransactionManager running on Jboss/wildfly.

Some of the methods that manipulate the database also call a bean which contains a LinkedBlockingQueue. This queue stores logging messages that are periodically dispatched to someplace else on another thread (using simple spring @Scheduler).

Would it be possible to make my queue (inside a bean) transactional? ie. if the transaction rollback would I be able to "undo" any operations made on my Collection? What's the best strategy to implement this ?

So, in short something like:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public PersonService {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager EM;

    @Autowired
    LoggingBuffer logger;

    public void addPerson(String name) {
          EM.persist(new Person(.....));

          logger.add("New person!");

          // A rollback here via some thrown exception would not affect the queue
    }
}

@Component
public class LoggingBuffer {

     private Queue<String> q= new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

     public add(String msg){
        q.add(msg);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
@Transactional
public void addPerson(String name) {
          EM.persist(new Person(.....));

          //logger.add("New person!");

          // A rollback here via some thrown exception would not affect the queue
    }
public void wrapAddPerson(String name){
     List<String> localBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
try{
    addPerson(name);
    localBuffer.add(".....");
}catch(Exception e)
{
   localBuffer.clear();
}  
 finally{
      localBuffer.forEach(logger::add);
  }

}
```